# bootstrap grid system control-group not lining up - Panells

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been using Bootstrap 3 to design my screens but I'm having an issue with controls NOT starting from the left when using control-group.  Most of the time it works fine, but now and then I get 1 label that simply refuses to start on a new line - and will wrap onto the previous line:

Here is a section of my code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">PPE and Ladders</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Site Specific PPE:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="siteSpecificPPE" name="siteSpecificPPE" tabindex=10></input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Comments:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="PPEComments" name="PPEComments" tabindex=10></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Ladder ID:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="laddersID" name="laddersID" tabindex=10></input>
      </div>
      <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Safety Catches:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="safetyCatchesWorking" name="safetyCatchesWorking" tabindex=10></input>
      </div>
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Warn. Sign:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="warningSign" name="warningSign" tabindex=10></input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Comments:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="equipmentComments" name="equipmentComments" tabindex=1></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- panel-body -->
</div>
<!-- panel panel-primary -->
```

In the illustration below you can see the issue.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4gtk.png)

Has anyone got any ideas on how to cure this... driving me potty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

As you said, you were having margin issues, it was due to the gutter of `-15px` created on left and right by using `class="row"`.

You need to wrap all your `row` class inside `container`/`container-fluid` class.

Like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   </div>
</div>
```

---

Never forget to add `class="row"` if you need to align the columns in one line.

Also make sure you sum up the columns to 12 in a row.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">PPE and Ladders</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Site Specific PPE:</label>
          <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input type="checkbox" id="siteSpecificPPE" name="siteSpecificPPE" tabindex=10 />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Comments:</label>
          <div class="col-xs-9">
            <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="PPEComments" name="PPEComments" tabindex=10></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Ladder ID:</label>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="laddersID" name="laddersID" tabindex=10 />

          </div>
          <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Safety Catches:</label>
          <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="safetyCatchesWorking" name="safetyCatchesWorking" tabindex=10></input>
          </div>
          <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Warn. Sign:</label>
          <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="warningSign" name="warningSign" tabindex=10></input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Comments:</label>
          <div class="col-xs-9">
            <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="equipmentComments" name="equipmentComments" tabindex=1></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- panel-body -->
</div>
<!-- panel panel-primary -->
```

Comment: Thanks Dhaval... Yes the Row Class works great.  I had to change the CSS as it was adding 15px to both the left and right margins, causing a slight alignment issue, but i managed to cure it.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Please check the update, as it's better than editing your CSS.